# Converting GRIB to Geotiff with gdal_translate in Python

Tags: qgis, python, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate, grib

I want to extract each band from a GRIB (gridded binary from http://data-portal.ecmwf.int/data/d/interim_daily/) in a single Geotiff image. I´m using Python with gdal_translate in a QGIS backround, but the dgal_translate command doesn´t work.

The import of the GRIB-data works well, but in my loop about all bands, where I want to execute the gdal_translate command I get an error.
The loop also works well, but it tells me, that the algorithm for the GDAL command is unknown (I imported the tool in my script).

I get the information (in the QGIS console) while running: "Algorithm not found" (I get this information for each band, but the program continues).
There is no other explicit error warning.
My code:

```
import os 
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr from

filename='C:\\Users\\mypath\\test1.grib' rasterInput =
gdal.Open(filename, GA_ReadOnly)

if rasterInput is None:
    print 'Grib import failed'

print 'Grib imported'

bandCount = rasterInput.RasterCount print bandCount


format = "GTiff" driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)

for a in range(bandCount):


    outputFile = 'C:/Users/mypath/Geotiffs/%s.tif' %(a+1)

    translate = processing.runalg('translate, -b %s, -co COMPRESS=NONE, -co BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED, -of GTiff, %s, %s' %(a+1, rasterInput, outputFile))

del bandCount
```

I copied and pasted this command from the QGIS tool raster --> conversion --> translate, but it just works for one band not for all in range automatically.

How can I do this per command-line?

I´m a beginner at Python and GDAL and I can´t find any satisfying result.

I hope that is explicit enough for some answers.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more? For example, what is the exact error you get? What do you mean by "dgal_translate doesn't work" - we assume you mean gdal_translate, but what happens instead. Does it work using the same data on the command line? What is the source of your GRIB file? Please edit the question to add more information.